# Combining meta_search with acts_as_taggable_on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on, meta-search

I've run into a small problem with some search-functionality for a Rails 3 website I'm developing. I have a simple `Post` model that looks like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
end
```

I'm using `acts_as_taggable_on` to make adding tags to my posts a bit easier. When I have a post tagged 'rails' and I do the following, all works well:

```
@posts = Post.tagged_with("rails")
```

Thing is, I also want to search for the title of the post. When I have a post titled 'Hello world' and tagged 'rails', I want to be able to find this post by searching for 'hello' **or** 'rails'. So I want a `LIKE` statement for the title column in combination with the `tagged_with` method `acts_as_taggable_on` provides. The `where` scope doesn't work, because it uses `AND` instead of `OR`.

I hoped `meta_search` would fix the problem, but this isn't working for me. I tried several things. Here are two examples of what I tried:

```
@search = Post.search(:tagged_with_or_title_like => params[:search])
@search = Post.search(:title_like => params[:search], :tagged_with => params[:search])
```

It just doesn't recognize 'tagged_with'. It's my first time using `meta_search`, so I might be doing something wrong here. ;) I've read somewhere that `searchlogic` worked in combination with `acts_as_taggable_on`, but since it doesn't support Rails 3, I can't use that.

I hoped somebody here could help me with this problem. Anyone know how to combine `acts_as_taggable_on` with `meta_search`? Or maybe know a solution without `meta_search`? Also, if there's a better option for `acts_as_taggable_on` that works with `meta_search` I'd love to hear that too. :)

**EDIT:**
I got it working without using `tagged_with` or `meta_search`. It looked like this:

```
Post.select("DISTINCT posts.*").joins(:base_tags).where("posts.title LIKE ? OR tags.name = ?", "%"+params[:search]+"%", params[:search])
```

The query created was ridiculous, so I tried a different route: without `acts_as_taggable_on` and `meta_search`. I created a tags table myself and connected it to the posts with `has_and_belongs_to_many`. I won't have other tables that need to be connected to the tags, so this will do the trick for me. I created a scope for searching both the tags and title:

```
scope :search, lambda { |search| select("DISTINCT posts.*").joins(:tags).where("posts.title LIKE ? OR tags.name = ?", "%"+search+"%", search) }
```

Now I can do the following:

```
Post.search(params[:search])
```

It works great and the query is also quite nice. Still, if anyone knows a better way: please tell me. It could also be helpful for the people coming here via Google.

Comment: I updated the question with how I solved it. I eventually just dropped acts_as_taggable and meta_search. Maybe you could try Serge's answer. If it works I'll mark it as answered. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Post.metasearch({:title_or_tag_taggings_tag_name_contains => params[:search]})
```

enjoy

Comment: I just tested if this works inside my old project and it works! So I'm marking this as answered. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution you're looking into is using database VIEW as new model.

You can create view containing join tables Post and Tags.

Then you can search it, using meta_search without problems.